# Admob Ads not showing, I have set up all the codes correctly, still not showing

Tags: java, android, firebase, admob

[This is App ID I have added it in Android Manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ko6V.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.rishavgmail.coder.carescountrysactionresourcesexigencyservices">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".UserLoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UserLoginPage" />
        <activity android:name=".UserRegistration" />
        <activity android:name=".AuthorizationLoginPage" />
        <activity android:name=".OtpStepOne" />
        <activity android:name=".VerifyPhone" />
        <activity android:name=".AuthorityRegistration" />
        <activity android:name=".AuthorityHome" />
        <activity android:name=".AuthReg" />
        <activity android:name=".AuthLoginPage" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"></activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-*******381606112~********91"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[My AdMob AdUnitId in the string.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSJ5x.jpg)

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">C A R E S : Country\'s Action Resources Exigency Services</string>
    <string name="open">Open</string>
    <string name="close">Close</string>
    <string name="event_name">Event/Party/Restaurant/Other Name </string>
    <string name="event_location">Event Address</string>
    <string-array name="events">
        <item>SELECT AN EVENT</item>
        <item>PARTY</item>
        <item>RESTAURANT</item>
        <item>OTHER EVENTS</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="foods">Foods</string>
    <string name="btn_send">Inform Authority</string>
    <string name="copyright">
        Developed by 16Bit Coders
    </string>
    <string name="userphone">
        Your Phone Number
    </string>
    <string name="user_login_button">
        LOGIN AS USER
    </string>
    <string name="authority_login_button">
        LOGIN AS AUTHORITY
    </string>
    <string name="user_email">Email</string>
    <string name="user_password">Password</string>
    <string name="confirm_password">Confirm Password</string>
    <string name="login">LOGIN</string>
    <string name="register">REGISTER</string>
    <string name="fname">First Name</string>
    <string name="lname">Last Name</string>
    <string name="welcome_authority">Authority Login</string>
    <string name="send_otp">SEND OTP</string>
    <string name="verify_otp">Verify OTP</string>
    <string name="enter_otp">Enter OTP</string>
    <string name="enter_aadhaar">Aadhar Card Number</string>
    <string-array name="gender">
        <item>SELECT GENDER</item>
        <item>MALE</item>
        <item>FEMALE</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="location">
        <item>91</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="thanks">Thank You So Much</string>
    <string name="thanks2">You Just Take a Part of Helping Needy People</string>
    <string name="hero">Awesome.. You are a real Hero !!</string>
    <string-array name="ngo_list">
        <item>Jeevan Life Seva Sangstha</item>
        <item>Astha Foundation</item>
        <item>AIWA NGO India</item>
        <item>All India Human Rights Bureau</item>
        <item>Chain Foundation</item>
        <item>Helping Hand Foundation</item>
        <item>Human Wellfair Foundation</item>

    </string-array>
    <string name="banner_ad">ca-app-pub-*******381606112/*******732</string>

</resources>
```

[I have called adunitId in the xml file from string.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYQWy.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="174dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="54dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".UserLoginActivity">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/user_login_button"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_button_style"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/user_login_button"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/authority_login_button"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_button_style"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/authority_login_button"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_login_button" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/copyright"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[And finally I setup java code to show ads in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olDRy.jpg)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class UserLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnLogin,btnAuthLogin;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private AdView adview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);
        adview = findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adview.loadAd(adRequest);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.user_login_button);
        btnAuthLogin = findViewById(R.id.authority_login_button);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this,UserLoginPage.class));
            }
        });
        btnAuthLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this,AuthLoginPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

What can I do now, I have researched on google, I have reviewed StackOverflow posts as well but I can't find any solution, how can I solve it.
Even as Google AdMob policy I just added one single ad in one activity only, still it not showing ads
Thank you

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please do not add screenshots of code.

Answer (score 0):

It takes up to 72 hours for AdMob to approve your account and start showing ads. You can use test ads until then.

[Test ad IDs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

Comment: But i tested my old Admob approved account as well, still its not working

Comment: In that case check if the adview has enough space to display the ad. If not ad won't show up. If that dosen't work you can check logcat output to find out what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I tested Test Ad, its working but real ads not working

Answer (score 0):

You have written every code but you no where initialize the Admob SDK. Initialize it as soon as the app launches using

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.YOUR_APP_ID));
```